# Using variables from different CMIP6 models

Tags: meteorology, models, climate-models

I would like to know if using variables (ex: sea surface temperature, precipitation, etc.) from two CMIP6 climate models to produce a species/niche distribution model is an accepted practice and won’t affect the produced model validity?  If it’s accepted, are there any limitations that should be considered (ex. variables should come from models of equal climate sensitivity, have the same model components, etc)?

Comment: Usually, all the variables for any analysis should come from the same model and experiment. This to ensure the physical consistency between the variables. For instance, if you use daily precipitation and temperature from different model outputs, you might find the temperature of a hot sunny day associated with the amount of precipitation of a cloudy and stormy day.